# Excel Logic based Result

Tags: excel, filter

What formula should I use to assign a value to column B depending on the value of column A?

Column A data looks like this:

```
12345
23456
34567
```

- If the first character of Column A is 1, Column B should show "Alpha"
- If the first character of Column A is 2, Column B should show "Beta"
- If the first character of Column A is 3, Column B should show "Gamma"

What logic should I use here?

Comment: Fix formatting and readability.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the CHOOSE function here. In B1 place this formula:

```
=CHOOSE(LEFT(A1),"Alpha","Beta","Gamma")
```

[image]

Comment: Much quicker than converting the first digit to the Greek numbering system.

Answer (score 0):

In B you could have: `IF(LEFT(A1;1)=1;"Alpha";IF(LEFT(A1;1)=2;"Beta";"Gamma"))`

Comment: not working! its not evaluating the function LEFT(A1;1)=1